# Travis build failing

Tags: cocoapods, travis-ci, swift3

I am trying to build a cocoapod with xcode8 on travis:

https://travis-ci.org/xtrinch/MRCountryPicker/builds/160232165

> $ pod lib lint
>
> - ERROR | [iOS] unknown: Encountered an unknown error (Must be in the root of the repo (/Users/travis/.cocoapods/repos/master), instead
>     in /Users/travis/build/xtrinch/MRCountryPicker.) during validation.
>     [!] MRCountryPicker did not pass validation, due to 1 error.-> MRCountryPicker (0.0.5)

It seems to me that travis has the wrong repository url. I am extremely confused. Can anybody help me identifying the issue?

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?

Comment: Not yet, the idea was to try manually override git source repo url before running pod lib lint, thats how i solved it locally, but i havent had the chance to test it yet. @joern